# What is the SQL query to find the name of employee who supervises more employees than any other supervisor?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the SQL query to find the name of employee who supervises more employees than any other supervisor?

```
Employee
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  Fname   |    Ssn    | Super_ssn |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| John     | 123456789 | 333445555 |
| Franklin | 333445555 | 888665555 |
| Alicia   | 999887777 | 987654321 |
| Jennifer | 987654321 | 888665555 |
| Ramesh   | 666884444 | 333445555 |
| Joyce    | 453453453 | 333445555 |
| Ahmad    | 987987987 | 987654321 |
| James    | 888665555 | NULL      |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT Fname
FROM Employee
WHERE Super_ssn >=ALL(Select Super_ssn
                        FROM Employee)
```

- Fname = name of the employee
- SSN = the employees SSN
- Supervisor_ssn = the SSN of the employees Supervisor
- The SSN table contains the Supervisor's SSN's as well. They are all in the same table
- DB is mySQL
- It is all the same table named "Employee"

Comment: can appreciate if you can post your tables otherwise will give you a pseudocode

Comment: @maSTArHiAn Done.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing here is just to list them by number of employees:

```
SELECT Supervisor_ssn, COUNT(SSN) as n 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Supervisor_ssn
ORDER BY n DESC
```

The one you want will come up on top.

Hope it helps

Comment: This works great and is the most practical solution. But how can we retrieve only the name of the employee at the top?

Comment: You can add LIMIT 1 at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you want a list ordered by who supervises the most to least, remove the LIMIT 1 clause

```
SELECT
    e1.`Fname`,
    COUNT(e2.`Fname`) AS `Num_Empl`
FROM `Employee` e1
JOIN `Employee` e2
ON e2.`Ssn` = e1.`Super_ssn`
GROUP BY e1.`Fname`
ORDER BY `Num_Empl` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```